# 正規表現を使用して、特定の文字の前の文字を削除したい

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

例えば、`●Ｎ◆ＸＹ時計` という文字列があるとき、文字`ＸＹ`は固定され、`●Ｎ◆`は記号問わず様々な文字、`時計`は様々な漢字やひらがなを取るとする。
このとき、固定されている`ＸＹ`までの先頭の文字を削除したいです。

正規表現を使えばできそうな気がしているのですが、正規表現で削除する方法がわかりません。
初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

wilwilco さんが自己回答されていますが、 `r'^[^ＸＹ]*'` では条件を満たしていないと思われます。
「ＸまたはＹではない任意の文字列」を削除しているため、例えば、以下の様な結果になります。

```
>>> re.sub(r'^[^ＸＹ]*', '', '●Ｎ◆ＹＹＸＹ時計')
'ＹＹＸＹ時計'
>>> re.sub(r'^[^ＸＹ]*', '', '●Ｎ◆ＹＹＹＸ時計')
'ＹＹＹＸ時計'
>>> re.sub(r'^[^ＸＹ]*', '', '●Ｎ◆Ｘ時計')
'Ｘ時計'
```

### 案1: 残したい文字列を指定し、キャプチャして使う

```
>>> re.sub(r'^.*(ＸＹ.*)', r'\1', '●Ｎ◆ＸＹ時計')
'ＸＹ時計'
>>> re.sub(r'^.*(ＸＹ.*)', r'\1', '●Ｎ◆ＹＹＸＹ時計')
'ＸＹ時計'
>>> re.sub(r'^.*(ＸＹ.*)', r'\1', '●Ｎ◆Ｘ時計')
'●Ｎ◆Ｘ時計'
```

ＸＹで始まる任意の文字列をキャプチャして、 `r'\1'` で置換後の文字列として使っています。

### 案2: 肯定先読みを使う

```
>>> re.sub(r'^.*(?=ＸＹ)', r'', '●Ｎ◆ＹＹＸＹ時計')
'ＸＹ時計'
>>> re.sub(r'^.*(?=ＸＹ)', r'', '●Ｎ◆ＸＹ時計')
'ＸＹ時計'
>>> re.sub(r'^.*(?=ＸＹ)', r'', '●Ｎ◆Ｘ時計')
'●Ｎ◆Ｘ時計'
```

`(?=...)` を使って、ＸＹの直前までを対象として、空文字列に置換しています。

### 補足

> `時計`は様々な漢字やひらがなを取る

私の回答にこの条件は含めていません。
漢字とひらがな、以外のどんな文字でも許容しています。
wilwilcoさんの回答も同様のため、今回はスルーしています。
（漢字とひらがなにのみ一致する正規表現はちょっと面倒なのです）

Answer (score 0):

色々と検討しまして、下記のような正規表現で期待通りできたかもしれません。

```
import re

a = re.sub(r'^[^ＸＹ]*', '', '●Ｎ◆ＸＹ時計')

print(a)
```